# PHP/MySQL - Count and display number based on date?

Tags: mysql

There is a total 3 records on the current date but it display only 1.

There were no error found.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```html
<?php

require_once("connect.php");

$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM bookings WHERE bookingDate = CURDATE()";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$numRow = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "<h1>".$numRow."</h1>";

?>
```

Comment: YOU WANT ONLY COUNT OR YOU WANT RECORDS ALSO FOR DISPLAY?

Comment: use=>  count(*) as total

Comment: @AlivetoDie I want to count it and display the total number of records. Just display the number of records not the table. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use count aggregation:

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM bookings 
WHERE bookingDate = CURDATE()
```

Comment: how can I echo the total number of records?

Comment: How can I print the total numbers of records?

<?php

require_once("connect.php");

$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM bookings WHERE bookingDate = CURDATE()";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

echo "$result";

?>

Comment: "how can I echo the total number of records? " use a alias in SQL  `COUNT(*) AS alias`  then you can get it in PHP like this `echo $row['alias']` @Res .. Without a SQL alias i think you can use `echo $row['count(*)']` in PHP to get the counts value not sure because i always use aliases when selecting which i advice you to do also.